# Pandas get ratio of a value from another df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe **df1**

```
    user_id
0    101
1    102
2    103
3    101
```

and another
**df2**

```
    user_id  type
0    101     cash
1    101     card
2    102     card
3    102     card
4    103     cash
5    103     cash
6    103     card
```

There are more than 2 types.

I want to add a columns to `df1` that is the ratio of each type for every `user_id`. So I want the `df1` to look like:

**df1**

```
    user_id  cash_pct  card_pct
0    101       0.5       0.5
1    102        0        1.0
2    103       0.67      0.33
3    101       0.5       0.5
```

I think I should use groupby, but beyond that I'm not sure how I should do about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize` parameter, rename columns names by [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and add [`DataFrame.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html), add to `df1` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = (df1.join(pd.crosstab(df2['user_id'], df2['type'], normalize='index')
                .add_suffix('_pct').round(2), on='user_id'))
print (df)
   user_id  card_pct  cash_pct
0      101      0.50      0.50
1      102      1.00      0.00
2      103      0.33      0.67
3      101      0.50      0.50
```